# GWT: How to capture simple MouseOverEvent for CellTable ?

Tags: gwt, handler, mouseover, celltable

I found a code that handles mouseover event whenever a user hovers over any cell:

```
                 table.addCellPreviewHandler(new Handler<List<String>>()
                    {

                        @Override
                        public void onCellPreview(
                            CellPreviewEvent<List<String>> event)
                        {
                            if ("mouseover".equals(event.getNativeEvent().getType())) {
                                Element cellElement = event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget().cast();
                                // play with element
                                System.out.println(" message !!");
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

When user hovers over title of columns, nothing happens.
Mouseover event should fire also when hovering over borders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```java
table.addDomHandler(new MouseOverHandler() {
   @Override
   public void onMouseOver(MouseOverEvent event) {
      // handle the event
   }
}, MouseOverEvent.getType());
```